# Running du command reports infinity as disk usage

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, btrfs

I'm trying to get the total size of what's stored in my home directory. To my surprise, it reports infinity after a few seconds:

```
/home/user $ du -sh .
Infinity
```

Huh? I'm pretty sure there are no recursive symlinks, but `du` should not follow symlinks anyways per default. I've also tried `du -shx .` so it won't cross device boundaries - with the same result.

I'm pretty sure I don't have infinite disk space or disk usage. ;-)

The target filesystem is a btrfs subvolume with no snapshots. `rsync` syncs this directory to an external disk just fine every night, it has no problem with this "infinity." However, `du` reports the same there.

**Answers to comments:**

There are no mount points within my home directory:

```
$ mount|grep home
/dev/sda3 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=lzo,space_cache,autodefrag)
```

Using the full path instead of `.` as parameter shows the same behavior.

There are no files bigger than 200GB:

```
$ sudo find -size +$((200*1024*1024)) | wc -l
0
```

Comment: You don't maybe have a glusterfs mount point in a subdirectory? I've seen this happening with glusterfs mount points before

Comment: Weird. Do you get the same output with the full path? `du -sh /home/hurikhan/`.

Comment: amended my post to answer your questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this](http://gnu-coreutils.7620.n7.nabble.com/bug-14767-du-s-reports-Infinity-td21880.html) bug report where a user had the same issue on a btrfs system. It turned out that the problem came from a specific `.xml` file whose size was incorrectly reported as 16 exabytes.

In the case of the person who filed the bug, the issue was a filesystem corruption and the problem was solved by moving all files to `/tmp` (which was a tmpfs), deleting the originals and then copying them back again:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo &&
cp -rv ~/* /tmp/foo &&
rm -r ~/* &&
mv /tmp/foo/* ~/
```

Comment: I've updated my question: There are no such big files.

Comment: Thanks to your link to the bug report I've narrowed it down to the chromium cache directory using `du -shx $(ls -a | tail -n +3)` and following the "infinite" path. Interesting: diving into the `.cache/chromium/Default/Cache` the problem vanished although `du -sh Cache` reported infinity. I've removed the directory and the problem is gone now.

Comment: Marking your answer as accepted although it seems to be a different bug. At least it helped me tracking it down to the offending path.

Comment: @hurikhan77 sounds like the same issue. A random file giving problems. It would be interesting to know if moving the cache and moving it back would have fixed it.

Comment: Well, exploring the cache directory itself didn't show the behavior - so it was probably not a file. Maybe a directory node was damaged, I have no idea. After all: btrfs is still experimental and I had a few system crashes in the past and btrfs reports some non-fatal inode issues in btrfsck. But I think those are unrelated as the rsync backup shows the same behavior.

Comment: I'd add "&&" between critical commands successions (ie, not rm if something went wrong in the cp?)

Comment: upvoted :)  But now I wonder if another solution wouldn't be to run some kind of fsck (appropriate to the filesystem) instead?

Comment: @OlivierDulac no idea. I'm just parroting what I found in that bug report. I've never touched btrfs and don't know much about filesystems in general anyway.